# TTF font in a Windows Phone 8 application

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, fonts, truetype

I have Windows Phone 7 application where a font works fine, but in a Windows Phone 8 application the same font doesn't work. Apparently, that is font licensing issue. There is a flag in the TTF file which indicates whether the font can be embedded or not. How to change font embeddability, or is there is there some workaround to include the same font in WP8 application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at http://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2013/06/22/TTF-Font-with-Windows-Phone-8.aspx. This article for wp8 mentions multiple ways of embeding font, including a licensing issue problem.